# why my data is not retrieving from real-time database using api in flutter for web

Tags: flutter, http, dart, firebase-realtime-database, web-applications

I am trying to fetch data from real-time database firebase in flutter for web-app. So, i have tried couple ways but couldn't make it work. These are my current codes for retrieving data from realtime database.

i am trying to fetch data into listview.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:nasofficialproject/Modals/PostsModals.dart';
import 'package:nasofficialproject/Provider/Upin.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DashboardPageState createState() => _DashboardPageState();
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {

  final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  List<PostModels> postmodal = [];
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var pro;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pro = Provider.of<upin>(context, listen: false);
    getPostList();
  }

  Future<void> getPostList() async {
    final values = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://officialnasproject-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Schools/${pro.upin1}/School-Posts.json'));
    var val = json.decode(values.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

    val.forEach((key, value) {
      PostModels postModels = new PostModels(
        value['PostContent'],
        value['PostUserName'],
        value['PostDate'],
        value['PostUserRole'],
        value['PostTitle'],
        value['PostUploader'],
        value['Upin'],
      );
      postmodal.add(postModels);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Flexible(
          child: postmodal.length == 0 ? Center(
            child: SelectableText("No posts yet....", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),) :
          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: postmodal.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return CardUI(
                  postmodal[index].PostContent,
                  postmodal[index].PostUserName,
                  postmodal[index].PostDate,
                  postmodal[index].PostUserRole,
                  postmodal[index].PostTitle,
                  postmodal[index].PostUploader,
                  postmodal[index].Upin,
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget CardUI(String PostContent, String PostUserName, String PostDate, String PostUserRole, String PostTitle, String PostUploader, String Upin)
  {
    return Card(
      child: Container(
                child: Column(
                    children: <Widget> [
                      Text(PostUserName,),
                     Text('@'+PostUserRole,),
                      Text(PostTitle,),
                      Text(PostContent),
                ],
            ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

These are the codes i am using for fetching and showing data but i don't know where why its not working. Can someone help me, it would mean world to me because i am trying to solve this issue for four consecutive days but haven't got it yet.

Answer (score 0):

First time you create your Widget, it will run initState, but it will run build while you are fetching the data - and there is nothing yet to show.

Once your data is received - there is nothing that tells the Widget to rebuild.

The best approach would be to use FutureBuilder. What it will do - it will render the what you want while you are waiting for the data - in my exmample below it will render CircularProgressIndicator,. Once the future completes, it will render again - this time showing your data.

Something like this (I didn't try to compile, so it might needs few corrections):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:nasofficialproject/Modals/PostsModals.dart';
import 'package:nasofficialproject/Provider/Upin.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DashboardPageState createState() => _DashboardPageState();
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {

  final fb = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  List<PostModels> postmodal = [];
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var pro;
  Future<void> _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pro = Provider.of<upin>(context, listen: false);
    _future=getPostList();
  }

  Future<void> getPostList() async {
    final values = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://officialnasproject-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Schools/${pro.upin1}/School-Posts.json'));
    var val = json.decode(values.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

    val.forEach((key, value) {
      PostModels postModels = new PostModels(
        value['PostContent'],
        value['PostUserName'],
        value['PostDate'],
        value['PostUserRole'],
        value['PostTitle'],
        value['PostUploader'],
        value['Upin'],
      );
      postmodal.add(postModels);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
             future: _future,
             builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
if (snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting) return CircularProgressIndicator();

return Container(
        child: Flexible(
          child: postmodal.length == 0 ? Center(
            child: SelectableText("No posts yet....", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),) :
          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: postmodal.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return CardUI(
                  postmodal[index].PostContent,
                  postmodal[index].PostUserName,
                  postmodal[index].PostDate,
                  postmodal[index].PostUserRole,
                  postmodal[index].PostTitle,
                  postmodal[index].PostUploader,
                  postmodal[index].Upin,
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    )});
  }

  Widget CardUI(String PostContent, String PostUserName, String PostDate, String PostUserRole, String PostTitle, String PostUploader, String Upin)
  {
    return Card(
      child: Container(
                child: Column(
                    children: <Widget> [
                      Text(PostUserName,),
                     Text('@'+PostUserRole,),
                      Text(PostTitle,),
                      Text(PostContent),
                ],
            ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```